# Using distinct and then an aggregate function in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, distinct, aggregate-functions

This is a pretty basic problem and for whatever reason I can't find a reasonable solution. I'll do my best to explain.

Say you have an event ticket (section, row, seat #). Each ticket belongs to an attendee. Multiple tickets can belong to the same attendee. Each attendee has a worth (ex: Attendee #1 is worth $10,000). That said, here's what I want to do:

```
1. Group the tickets by their section
2. Get number of tickets (count)
3. Get total worth of the attendees in that section
```

Here's where I'm having problems: If Attendee #1 is worth $10,000 and is using 4 tickets, sum(attendees.worth) is returning $40,000. Which is not accurate. The worth should be $10,000. Yet when I make the result distinct on the attendee, the count is not accurate. In an ideal world it'd be nice to do something like

```
select 
    tickets.section, 
    count(tickets.*) as count, 
    sum(DISTINCT ON (attendees.id) attendees.worth) as total_worth 
from 
    tickets 
    INNER JOIN 
    attendees ON attendees.id = tickets.attendee_id 
GROUP BY tickets.section
```

Obviously this query doesn't work. How can I accomplish this same thing in a single query? OR is it even possible? I'd prefer to stay away from sub queries too because this is part of a much larger solution where I would need to do this across multiple tables.

Also, the worth should follow the ticket divided evenly. Ex: $10,000 / 4. Each ticket has an attendee worth of $5,000. So if the tickets are in different sections, they take their prorated worth with them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I'm having the exact same type of problem and I'm wondering if you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate the tickets before the attendees:

```
select ta.section, sum(ta.numtickets) as count, sum(a.worth) as total_worth
from (select attendee_id, section, count(*) as numtickets
      from tickets
      group by attendee_id, section
     ) ta INNER JOIN
     attendees a
     ON a.id = ta.attendee_id
GROUP BY ta.section
```

You still have a problem of a single attendee having seats in multiple sections. However, you do not specify how to solve that (apportion the worth?  randomly choose one section?  attribute it to all sections?  canonically choose a section?)

Comment: Thanks for this, but isn't this still counting the worth multiple times? The worth is determined by the number of tickets. Ex: Attendee #1 has a worth of $10,000 and is using 4 tickets. Each ticket contributes $5,000 to the worth. So if each ticket was in a different section, it would add $5,000 to its respective section. Does that make sense?

Comment: Doesn't this generate an error? The derived table ("ta") does not group properly. I'm pretty sure PostgreSQL will reject that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Yes, I fixed the code to match my intent.

Answer (score 0):

Using jsonb_object_agg:

```sql
select 
    tickets.section, 
    count(tickets.*) as count, 
    (
      SELECT SUM(value::int4)
      FROM jsonb_each_text(jsonb_object_agg(attendees.id, attendees.worth))
    ) as total_worth
from 
    tickets 
    INNER JOIN 
    attendees ON attendees.id = tickets.attendee_id 
GROUP BY tickets.section
```